# Need javascript equivalent to HTML input tag

Tags: javascript, input

I have a settings page that is full of forms, normally the values get submitted back to the server using the input tags. I have one instance that requires an alertbox to display a warning with a yes and no button, this part I have done, what I need to know is how to submit the value from a radio button back to the server in the same way the input tag does?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function radioFunc()
    {
    var x;
    var r=confirm("WARNING! \nManually adjusting flowrate settings can flood your process, Are you sure?");
    if (r==true)
      {
      x="YES!";
      }
    }
    </script>
```

...

```
<FORM action=/menu/index.zhtml method=post>
               <TR>
                  <TD width="45%">Max Flowrate Span </TD>
                  <TD align=middle width="25%"><INPUT value="<?z echo($configData.span420) ?>" name=configData.span420></TD>
                  <TD align=middle width="30%"><INPUT type=submit value=Submit><INPUT type=reset value=Reset></TD>
               </TR>
               <TR>
                  <TD width="45%">Desired Span </TD>
                  <TD align=middle width="25%">0%<input type="radio" name="ang" checked>25%<input type="radio" name="ang">50%<input type="radio" name="ang"><br>75%<input type="radio" name="ang">100%<input type="radio" name="ang" ></TD>
                  <TD align=middle width="30%"><button onclick="radioFunc()">Submit</button></TD>
               </TR>

            </FORM>
```

Comment: Add a hidden value `<input type'hidden' id='...' />` and set it's value in your function. It will then be posted with the form.

Comment: asawyer's answer is better than the two posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
if (r==true)
  {
  x="You pressed OK!";
  }
else
  {
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Replace

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
```

with setting the value of a hidden input on the form like:

```
<input type'hidden' id='hiddenAttr' />
```

and

```
document.getElementById("hiddenAttr").innerHTML=x;
```

You will then be able to access the hiddenAttr input the same as for the other attributes.

Comment: Please bear with me here, I'm an embedded programmer not a web developer. So I Replace "document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
" with "document.getElementById("hiddenAttr").innerHTML=x;
" and put "<input type'hidden' id='hiddenAttr' />
" in the Form with the radio buttons?

Comment: Yes. You need to create a new input field which has a type of hidden. You then want to select this by ID and set the innerHTML value to be equal to what the user selected. When this is posted you can extract the value just as if it was any other input type.

Comment: Got it working using the java submit method instead, had some problem on my callback function but now it works. Just one last problem, OK and Cancel both equate as true.